# turtlebot not moving with teleop in indigo

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**tl;dr**
Running the simulation of turtlebot in Gazebo, I can't get the turtlebot to move with the turtlebot_teleop package. I launch the appropriate nodes, the right windows come up, and when I hit the q/w/e keys, nothing happens.

**Long version**
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14 and ROS Indigo today so I could get going with Turtlebot. I'm using Gazebo 2.2.3.

I am working through the turtlebot tutorial, and everything is fine up to the Stage Simulator. for the world navigation simulation, I entered:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

Things *generally* seem to be working: when I launche turlebot_world.launch, it says:

```
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly
```

On the other hand I do get one error during initialization:

```
Error [SDF.cc:788] Missing element description for [pointCloudCutoffMax]
```

The nodes after launch:

/bumper2pointcloud
/cmd_vel_mux
/depthimage_to_laserscan
/gazebo
/laserscan_nodelet_manager
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard

Ouptut of *rqt_graph*:

[image: image description]

The Gazebo screen is up, I see the simulated turtlebot in its little room. It is not stuck against a bureau or anything. I get the following output on the teleop screen when I press different keys to try to make the thing move:

[image: image description]

I expect the little guy to be moving by default, and especially when I enter q/w/e (maybe there is some additional launch code or GO signal I'm ignorant of?). *[edit: that last parenthetic remark was key]* Nothing. He's just sitting there. Unlike the problem at the following link, I do not have multiple distributions of ROS (or Gazebo) on my system, so this likely isn't an issue with conflicting software versions:
http://answers.ros.org/question/29983/turtlebot_teleop-not-working-properly/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240775/turtlebot-not-moving-with-teleop-in-indigo/) by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Problem:**
Stupidity.

**Solution:**
RTFM.

**Details**
By pressing q/w/e you are changing default speeds. To actually make it move at those speeds, you need to press the keys in the 'Moving around' matrix that you included in the picture of what you see in the teleop terminal. E.g., 'u, i, and o'.

So, in the printout on the screen when it said that w/x increased the speed, I took that to mean press w/x to make it move. I didn't notice the large matrix of movement instructions:

```
Moving around:
   u    i    o
   j    k    l
   m    ,    .
```

When I started to press *these* keys, the turtle began to move around in the map. Basically the instructions are a topographic map:

> u : rotate ccw and move forward (forward left)
> i : move forward
> o : rotate cw and move forward (forward right)
> j : rotate ccw
> k : stop
> l : rotate cw
> m : rotate cw and move back (backward left)
> , : move back
> . : rotate ccw and move back (backward right)

So...oops.

---

Originally posted by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) with karma: 39 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wbadry](https://answers.ros.org/users/45332/wbadry/) on 2021-06-16**:
LOL . Add me to this :)